# Different text for each image in image viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, layout-inflater

I used viewpager class to display sets of images instead of gallery class as its deprecated and customized it to show the text by using the below code , the problem is the same text showed for all images , what im trying to get is :  **Different text for each image** , which explain it , lets say we have  5 images , it must has 5 different text each one describe its image .

any advice will be appreciated , thanks

The code:

**ImagePager**

```
   public class ImagePager extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, imageArra);
    ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myimagepager);
    myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    myPager.setCurrentItem(0);}

private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c,
                              R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e};        }
```

**ImagePagerAdapter**

```
   public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

Activity activity;
int imageArray[];

public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra) {
    imageArray = imgArra;
    activity = act;}

public int getCount() {
    return imageArray.length;}

public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)collection.getContext
                 ().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pager, null);   

    ImageView im=(ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.myimage);             
    im.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

    TextView txt=(TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image_text);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout, 0);
       return layout;   }

@Override
public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
    ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
            }

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
    return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
                      }

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
              }   }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical">
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
   android:id="@+id/myimagepager" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

**custom_pager.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent" 
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:background="#FFDAB9" 
   android:gravity="center_horizontal">
 <ImageView android:id="@+id/myimage" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="0dp" 
   android:layout_margin="5dp" 
   android:layout_weight="2" /> 
 <TextView android:id="@+id/image_text" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:textColor="#B22222" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:text="text to image" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could pass an array of Strings into your adapter that correspond to each image..
ex.

In the activity declare your string array with your list of images..

```
private int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c,
                              R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e};  

private String[] stringArray = new String[] { "Image a", "Image b","Image c","Image d","Image e"};
```

Then when instantiating your adapter..

```
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, imageArra, stringArray );
```

In your adapter:

```
int imageArray[];
String[] stringArray;
public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra, String[] stringArra) {
    imageArray = imgArra;
    activity = act;
    stringArray = stringArra;
}
```

Then assign the text value from the array

```
TextView txt=(TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image_text);
txt.setText(stringArray[position]);
```

Comment: ok but how to specify certain text for each image , which mean each image will have different text than another image ,thanks

Comment: please one point i want to understand , i used viewholder with gallery class before when i want to add text to my images , but here in viewpager we did not use it , or the viewpager class behaviour doesnt need that , can you explain that please , thanks.

Comment: Here's a link that will explain the use of ViewHolder- http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166  I don't believe ViewHolder is important to use in a ViewPager since recycling Views isn't critical (performance won't be affected)