# android - crash because of changing static array list to deynamic

Tags: android, android-viewpager

i have use this 
[Different text for each image in image viewpager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664662/different-text-for-each-image-in-image-viewpager)

but when i want to have this:

```
public String[] stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarry);
```

instead of using static as

```
stringArray = new String[] { "Image a", "Image b","Image c","Image d","Image e"};
```

the application crashes and i really dont know why.

here is my LogCat :

```
04-22 14:56:37.002: D/dalvikvm(1066): GC freed 954 objects / 73824 bytes in 121ms
04-22 14:56:37.142: D/AndroidRuntime(1066): Shutting down VM
04-22 14:56:37.142: W/dalvikvm(1066): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-22 14:56:37.152: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.mypackage.pager.ImagePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ImagePagerAdapter.java:38)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter.instantiateItem(PagerAdapter.java:110)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:800)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:929)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:880)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1374)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:888)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:350)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:464)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:278)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3023)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:7964)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:763)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1633)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-22 14:56:37.182: E/AndroidRuntime(1066):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 14:56:37.232: I/dalvikvm(1066): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-22 14:56:37.232: E/dalvikvm(1066): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

also this is my ImagePagerAdapter

```
package com.mypackage.pager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    Activity activity;
    int imageArray[];
    String[] stringArray;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra, String[] StringArra) {
        imageArray = imgArra;
        activity = act;
        stringArray = StringArra;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return imageArray.length;
    }

    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_pager, null);

        ImageView im = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.myimage);
        im.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

        TextView txt = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.image_text);
        txt.setText(stringArray[position]);  **//Line 38**
        ((ViewPager) collection).addView(layout, 0);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View arg0, int arg1, Object arg2) {
        ((ViewPager) arg0).removeView((View) arg2);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        return arg0 == ((View) arg1);
    }

    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and ImagePager

```
package com.mypackage.pager;

import com.mypackage.pager.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class ImagePager extends Activity {


    public int imageArra[] = { R.drawable.p4a_001, R.drawable.p4a_002, R.drawable.p4a_003,
            R.drawable.p4a_004, R.drawable.p4a_005,R.drawable.p4a_006,R.drawable.p4a_007 };
    public String[] stringArray ;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, imageArra,
                stringArray);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myimagepager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);


    }


}
```

BTW as i said it works just fine with static names like the ones in provided link.
but i want dynamic method.thanks in advance.

Comment: Please highlight line 38 in ImagePagerAdapter.java.

Comment: do u have a textview named image_text custom_pager.xml file?

Comment: yes ofc i do, as i said it works just fine with static text as: stringArray = { "Image a", "Image b","Image c","Image d","Image e"};but what i want is to get it to work with stringArray that i have in values folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the statement `stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray);` before using stringArray i.e., `ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, imageArra,stringArray);`. Without this you are passing the `null` value to the ImagePagerAdapter.

i.e., the onCreate() code must be as below

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myarray); 
        ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, imageArra,
                stringArray);
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myimagepager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        myPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
```

Comment: wow thank you very much, that fixed it. i really need a lot more to learn.thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try initialising the String array BEFORE you use it.